# Linker errors when calling C++/CLI code from pure C++ code

Tags: c++, c++-cli, linker-errors

I am using VS2012 and I am trying to call CLI code from C++. So I created two projects. One is executable which is pure C++ (without CLI support) and second is dynamic library which is CLI (with /clr switch). If I have main (in executable):

```
// main.cpp file
#include "..\CLILibrary\CCli.h"

int main()
{
    Ccli test = Ccli();
    test.Write();
    return 0;
}
```

And one class in CLI library (build with CLR switch on):

```
// Ccli.h file
#pragma once

class Ccli
{
public:
    void Write();
    void CallRealCLIClass();
};

// Ccli.cpp file
#include " Ccli.h"

void Ccli::Write()
{
    System::Console::WriteLine("In Ccli class.");
}

void Ccli::CallRealCLIClass()
{
    // here I would like to call RealCLI class
}
```

Everything works fine so far. I understand, that header file (Ccli.h) cannot use anything from CLI since it has to be readable for my executable which is purely in C++ (theoretically it could if I would use something like #ifdef _MANAGED but thatÆs not my point). But in source file (Ccli.cpp) it is fine.

But now I want to use class which will be fully CLI. And I want to call it from Ccli.cpp file. So I created following class in my CLI library:

```
// RealCLI.h file
#pragma once
ref class RealCLI
{
public:
    RealCLI(void);
    System::String^ GetString();
    void Write(System::String^ s);
};
// RealCLI.cpp file
#include "RealCLI.h"

RealCLI::RealCLI(void){}

System::String^ GetString()
{
    System::String^ s = gcnew System::String("GetString in RealCLI class");
    return s;
}

void Write(System::String^ s)
{
    System::Console::WriteLine(s);
}
```

Now I have following problem and I don't know why. I get this error from linker:

Error   1   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000002) RealCLI::GetString   ...\RealCLI\RealCLI.obj

Error   2   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000003) RealCLI::Write ...\RealCLI\RealCLI.obj

Error   3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   ...\Debug\RealCLI.dll   1

So my library is fine (it is built without problem) but my executable have these linker errors. I don't understand why? I don't use this file in my executable project, so why is my executable even care about it? I find a way how to fix it. But since I don't know the reason why is the original program not working I consider it just as workaround. My workaround is delete RealCLI.cpp file and put everything in header file:

```
// RealCLI.h file
#pragma once

ref class RealCLI
{
public:
    RealCLI(void) {}

    // I cannot even put definition outside declaration of my class
    System::String^ GetString()
    {
        System::String^ s = gcnew System::String("GetString in RealCLI class");
        return s;
    }

    void Write(System::String^ s)
    {
        System::Console::WriteLine(s);
    }
};
```

Why is that? What am I doing wrong? Is some of my assumptions wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
// Ccli.cpp file
#include " Ccli.h"
// !!!added this line:
#include "RealCLI.h"

void Ccli::Write()
{
    System::Console::WriteLine("In Ccli class.");
}

void Ccli::CallRealCLIClass()
{
    // here I would like to call RealCLI class
}
```

I repaired namespaces in RealCli.cpp which helped. But when I added #include "RealCLI.h" I get these error anyway:

Error   2   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) RealCLI::.ctor   D:\ftp\my\vyuka-cppToCLI-test\vyuka-ManagedUmanaged\UnmanagedToManagedSource.obj

Error   3   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000002) RealCLI::GetString   D:\ftp\my\vyuka-cppToCLI-test\vyuka-ManagedUmanaged\UnmanagedToManagedSource.obj

Error   4   error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000003) RealCLI::Write   D:\ftp\my\vyuka-cppToCLI-test\vyuka-ManagedUmanaged\UnmanagedToManagedSource.obj

Error   5   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   D:\ftp\my\vyuka-cppToCLI-test\Debug\vyuka-ManagedUmanaged.exe   1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I didn't set linker right. Code is (after edit) Ok. I'm linking to .obj files, because I get errors when linking directly to .dll (because it is not pure C++ but CLI). And I linked just Ccli.obj then few weeks later I add another file and forgot link RealCLI.obj...

Answer (score 1):

You are making basic C++ mistake. In RealCLI.cpp:

Instead of:

`System::String^ GetString() { ... }`

use:

`System::String^ RealCLI::GetString() { ... }`

Similarly for `Write()`

Comment: Now I feel a bit stupid. But thank you. However it doesn't solve my problem. If I add include "RealCLI.h"  into Ccli.cpp file I still get linker errors. I added this to my original question.